# Why is this relation not reflexive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Determine whether the relation R on the set of all Web
pages is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, and/or transitive,
where (a, b) ∈ R if and only if
there is at least one common link onWeb page a and
Web page b.

Why is this relation not reflexive?

Comment: Note that, perhaps somewhat counterintuitively, the seemingly stronger condition that the pages have *all* their links in common *does* yield a reflexive relation (in fact an equivalence relation).

Comment: If a web page has any link at all, then it has a link in common with itself and thus is related to itself.  But if a web page has no links at all then it *doesnt* have any links in common with itself and is no related to itself (or to any page). So either a page is related to itself or it has no links.  But having no links is an option.  (It's clearly symmetric [and not anti-symmetric] though, and easily seen to not be transitive.)

Answer (score 2):

Because a webpage can have no links.